# How can i use asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to know how to use the asp.net mvc? i am new to this technology and i decided to use it and i have downloaded MVC release 1.0 so i need to know the steps needed fro setup the framework as after setting up the framework do i need to do any configurations in VS? i need a tutorial for creating mvc project and an example with code for accessing database through mvc. and which version or release of mvc u advice me to use release 1 or 2 ?

And with respect to posting back i knew that mvc don't do post back like web forms instead it call controller so is this means that each view (.asox file) don't have a related .cs file or the .cs file is shared with many .aspx files ?

I know that  my question is not clear but i got confused from articles about mvc when i ask any question or  seatch about mvc many articles without practical example or direct answer to my questions in my mind

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont need to do any configuration in VS at all. after you installed ASP.NET MVC you got a new project type called ASP.NET MVC Web Application thats where your journey begins :)

a good place to start would be this little sample app http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc/#MVC_SampleApp

after this you should understand the basic concept of how ASP.NET MVC works

Answer (score 3):

Asp.net have some good basic tutorials here http://www.asp.net/learn/mvc-videos/ and here http://www.asp.net/mvc/learn/. Hope they help you.

Answer (score 2):

You could start out reading [ScottGu's "Nerddinner" tutorial](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/04/28/free-asp-net-mvc-nerddinner-tutorial-now-in-html.aspx). It was originally published as part of the book titled "[Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470384611)", but has later been released freely on his blog. I believe the tutorial covers all the basics needed to get up and running.

If you feel you need more insight, I would suggest you look to Steven Sanderson's "[Pro ASP.NET MVC Framework](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210079)", rather than the aforementioned book. Sanderson's book seems to cover more detail on how stuff work, and he does a great job trying to promote best practices.

Answer (score 0):

Pick up a good book, e.g.- http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/03/10/free-asp-net-mvc-ebook-tutorial.aspx, or go to **http://www.asp.net** for tutorials.